# Block direct access to rtsp link

Tags: streaming, rtsp, rtp, libvlc, darwin

I'm planning building streaming server using Darwin Streaming Server and streaming player client with VLC library. My goals is only through my client that can access the video on Darwin Streaming Server. I don't want anyone access my RSTP link without using my client. Because when I get the any RTSP link like `rtsp://localhost/myvideo.mp4` I can directly play it on VLC player. But is it possible to block direct access to RTSP link without using the client I build by configuring on Darwin Streaming Server?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an authentication scheme to only allow authenticated users to access content at particular URL.

Essentially this means that the web application will only send responses to clients it has verified are who they say they are - otherwise it will send an error message or simply not reply.

There is an OWASP authentication cheat sheet for authentication here, which is kept up to date and is a good starting place for you to get an overview:

- https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Authentication_Cheat_Sheet

OWASP is an open industry organitsion focusing on application security -they describe themselves as:

> OWASP is an open community dedicated to enabling organizations to conceive, develop, acquire, operate, and maintain applications that can be trusted

Note that this will not stop authorised users being able to copy and potentially re-distribute the content. For that the typical defence is to encrypt the content and either build your own secure player and secure key exchange solution or use one of the standard DRM solutions which cover nearly all devices now.

Comment: I think authentication on web application is not the best solution for this. Because users still can see the RTSP link on their browser. like an example by opening the page source